# How to create a Yin Yang in Pixelmator

Tags: shapes, pixelmator

I have been trying to create a Yin Yang effect in Pixelmator and, whilst I have been relatively successful using a number of well-placed semi-circles, this method fails when I try to add a stroke to my shape, or change its colour.

So this is what I have done so far - please bear with me as I'm fairly inexperienced with graphic design software in general!

[image: Combining semi-circles...]

[image: ...to create a Yin Yang effect...]

4 semi-circles seem to do a good job of creating the effect. However, if you try to add a stroke that will go along the centre curve, the obvious happens:

[image: ...doesn't work when adding stroke]

So I have tried creating a third semi-circle to blank out the lower half of the shape. Ideally I want to find a way of telling Pixelmator to delete this section of the larger semi-circle:

[image: Using a blanking shape...]

I have merged the layers, although I'm not entirely sure what I should do next. If I try and give this layer stroke, I get this effect:

[image: ...still doesn't work with stroke...]

And if I try and give it a fill, this happens:

[image: ...or fill!]

Essentially, I wonder if I'm actually going about this completely wrong. I would be extremely grateful if anyone could offer any advice on the best way to achieve this.

Comment: +1 for actually showing your attempts and not just asking someone to do the work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I actually managed to fix it myself! After hours of trying, apparently writing the problem down helped me to think around the problem.

Not sure why it didn't occur to me before, I used the magic wand to make the 'blanking' semi-circle transparent and voila!

[image: Successful yin]

Thanks to those who gave this any thought.